# MTProto string type: are lengths measured in bytes or UTF-8 string length?

Tags: utf-8, telegram, mtproto

Looking at https://core.telegram.org/type/string it's unclear to me whether the length discussed here is the UTF-8 string length, or the number of bytes the string has been encoded into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On second reading it seems that it is the number of bytes:

> then L bytes of the string followed by 0 to 3 characters containing 0